# Error: HelloWorld has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

Tags: truffle, truffle-deployment, truffle-console

I'm following the steps in this [link](https://techbrij.com/setup-local-private-blockchain-deploy-smart-contract-ethereum-dapp-part-2) to create a truffle project.
I'm using ganache-cli as the ethereum client.

```
    rajkumar@rajkumar: Ethereum$ mkdir helloworld
    rajkumar@rajkumar: Ethereum$ cd helloworld/
    rajkumar@rajkumar: helloworld$ sudo truffle init

    ✔ Preparing to download
    ✔ Downloading
    ✔ Cleaning up temporary files
    ✔ Setting up box

    Unbox successful. Sweet!

    Commands:

    Compile:        truffle compile
    Migrate:        truffle migrate
    Test contracts: truffle test

    rajkumar@rajkumar: helloworld$ truffle create contract HelloWorld
    rajkumar@rajkumar: helloworld$ sudo truffle create contract HelloWorld
```

Then I updated the smart contract with the one in [here](https://techbrij.com/hello-world-smart-contract-solidity-ethereum-dapp-part-1).

```
    rajkumar@rajkumar: helloworld$ sudo truffle create migration HelloWorld
    rajkumar@rajkumar: helloworld$ sudo truffle migrate --network development
    [sudo] password for rajkumar:                                                                                                      

    Compiling your contracts...
    ===========================
    > Compiling ./contracts/HelloWorld.sol
    > Artifacts written to /home/rajkumar/Coding/Ethereum/helloworld/build/contracts
    > Compiled successfully using:
    - solc: 0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang

    Network up to date. 
    rajkumar@rajkumar: helloworld$ sudo truffle console
    truffle(development)> let instance = await HelloWorld.deployed()
    Thrown:
    Error: HelloWorld has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
        at Function.deployed (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/lib/contract/constructorMethods.js:61:1)
        at Object.checkNetworkArtifactMatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/lib/utils.js:256:1)
    truffle(development)>
```

Why I'm getting above error? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your HelloWorld migration file from migrate folder you should open it and by the tutorial add this:

```
var HelloWorld = artifacts.require('HelloWorld');

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  // Use deployer to state migration tasks.
  deployer.deploy(HelloWorld);
};
```

you should read the truffle document for more detail: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you deployed to the `development` network but are running `truffle console` with the default network, so assume that these are different.

You should deploy and use the console on the same network.

`truffle migrate --network development`
`truffle console --network development`

As an aside, you shouldn't have to use sudo.
You may want to consider installing packages locally.
I only have `ganache-cli` installed globally.
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/installing-packages-locally-rather-than-globally-npx/663

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
var BlockFinanceToken = artifacts.require("BlockFinanceToken.sol");

//function that is called through the deploy contract migration
//deployer is given by the truffle. deployer is the handler that
//provides handle to the blockchain.
//create initial token of the following number. This can the be the 
number of gift card vouchers
module.exports = async function (deployer) {
await deployer.deploy(BlockFinanceToken, 100000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the migrate folder create a file called 2_deploy_contracts.js

### file contents are:

```
var HelloWorld = artifacts.require("HelloWorld.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {

deployer.deploy(HelloWorld);

};
```

---

and run the migrate

$ truffle migrate

type
$ truffle console , hit enter

the type

```
"HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance) {return instance});"
```

then hit enter

along with that you can also type

```
"HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance) {return instance.getHelloMessage()});"
```

and then hit enter.