# Truffle deployment error in VS code

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-deployment, visual-studio-code

I am using Ganache and Truffle to deploy a practice smart contract from VS code. When I run:
HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance});
in the truffle development console, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught:
Error: HelloWorld has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Function.deployed (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/contract/constructorMethods.js:83:1)
    at Object.checkNetworkArtifactMatch (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/utils/index.js:249:1)
```

Here is the contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract HelloWorld{
    string private helloMessage = "Hello World";

    function getHelloMessage() public view returns (string memory) {
        return helloMessage;
    }
}
```

Here is the migration.js file:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

I have geth installed, not sure if that helps. Does anyone know what's going on? Thank you (:

Comment: What do the migration scripts do? Can you add those files to the question?

Comment: If that is the only migration file then you aren't deploying the contract. See this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/73757 it should have an example how to deploy a contract.